# Cannot get .desktop to open Jupyter Notebook and exit the terminal

Tags: .desktop, jupyter

I have had Jupyter Notebook installed from anaconda for a while, and I wanted to make a `.desktop` shortcut to open Jupyter Notebook without having to open anaconda every time or running from the terminal. Initially, I had the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Jupyter Notebook
Comment=Run Jupyter Notebook
Exec=$SHELL -c "source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate base &&  jupyter-notebook"
Terminal=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=application/x-ipynb+json;
Categories=Development;Education
```

This works perfectly, but the problem is that I also get a terminal window open with the process, which kind of ruins the point of having a `.desktop` when the initial intention was not to have a terminal window open. So, to close the terminal after opening JN, I tried changing the command to:

```
Exec=$SHELL -c "source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate base &&  jupyter-notebook & disown && exit"
```

which works perfectly when I run it in the terminal directly (`conda activate base &&  jupyter-notebook & disown && exit`). However, when I try to use it in the `.desktop`, a terminal window opens for about half a second and then it disappears, and JN does not even open.

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Note: I'm on kubuntu 20.04

Comment: Set `Terminal=false` in the desktop file.

Comment: Ok thanks @Terrance, I used `Exec=$SHELL -c "source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate base &&  jupyter-notebook & disown && exit"` and `Terminal=false` and it works now.